# Why the modified `toml` configuration for TiKV/PD does not take effect?

Tags: database, tidb, tikv, tidb-pd

During TiDB deployment, why the modified `toml` configuration for TiKV/PD does not take effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the --config parameter in TiKV/PD to make the toml configuration effective. TiKV/PD does not read the configuration by default. Currently, this issue only occurs when deploying using Binary. For TiKV, edit the configuration and restart the service. For PD, the configuration file is only read when PD is started for the first time, after which you can modify the configuration using pd-ctl. For details, see [PD Control User Guide](https://www.pingcap.com/docs/tools/pd-control/).